# GRUB is very slow after upgrading to an NVIDIA GPU

Tags: debian, boot, grub, initramfs

I'm using Debian for almost 7 years now and it runs flawlessly.
I have been using an AMD GPU for most of the time, but now I've purchased a NVIDIA RTX 3070 card for my system. I've performed a fresh install of Debian Bullseye on the system, but I'm running into a major issue, and i didn't find any fix yet.

When I start booting, GRUB takes a very very long time to initialize. I can see the message "Welcome to GRUB" appearing, and it will take more 5 seconds for the menu to appear. Furthermore the selection is terribly slow, and i got almost a 3 seconds delay in order to select my desired entry.

I've found some suggestion on how to fix this issue, like lowering the resolution and these things, but none of them helped in any way.

Also this issue is not limited to my local GRUB, but also to the GRUB menu of various Live-Linux systems like Parted Magic or Clonezilla.

I think the only way might be to revert back to an AMD GPU, but that's not what I want, only because of the GRUB menu struggling.

Maybe it's important to know, i use UEFI boot, not legacy boot.
Output of `systemd-analze`

```
Startup finished in 21.118s (firmware) + 10.133s (loader) + 15.778s (kernel) + 25.268s (userspace) = 1min 12.298s 
graphical.target reached after 25.260s in userspace
```

Comment: Are there any BIOS updates for your system? Sounds like your EFI firmware is struggling with your GPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately there are no further updates for my board. I got a ASRock X370 Killer SLI, and got the latest firmware already. I'm thinking about a board specific issue as well because i didn't find similar reports about this issue.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227735/grub-is-extremely-slow-1-second-per-key-input https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/480159

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that already, but unfortunately it didn't help it all, so i think i got a different issue.

Comment: You could try using rEFInd instead. It's a really great EFI boot manager. I personally like it a lot more than GRUB.